# React form not populating data

Tags: reactjs

I am working with some data and trying to populate a form dynamically. It works as I expected except when it comes to an array for one of the dropdowns. For some reason it will log to the console but not update the options.

```
import React, { useReducer} from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Products from '../data/Products';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const ProductForm= () => {
const useReducerState = (initialState = {}) => {    
    const reducer = (prev, next) => ({ ...prev, ...next });
    return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
};

const [state, setState] = useReducerState({
make: "",
model: "",
storage: "",
color: "",    
});

 const handleChange = (e) => {
    let proToUpdate = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    if (value){setState({ [proToUpdate]: value }); }              
}

 const {
    make,
    model,
    storage,
    color,
} = state;

 return (
    <Container>
    <form autoComplete='off'>
        <div className="form-group">
            <select name="make" className="hardwear" id="make" value={make} required onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="">Manufacturer</option>
               { Object.keys(Products["handset"]["hardwear"]).map(item => {
            return (<option value={item} key={uuidv4()}>{item}</option>);
          })} 
            </select>
            <select name="model" id="model" className="hardwear" value={model} onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="">Model</option>
                { make && ( Object.keys(Products["handset"]["hardwear"][state.make]).map(item => {
            return (<option value={item} key={uuidv4()}>{item}</option>);
          }))} 
            </select>
            <select name="storage" className="hardwear" value={storage} onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="">Storage</option>
                { model && (Products["handset"]["hardwear"][state.make][state.model]["storage"].forEach(item => {
                    console.log(item)
             return (<option value={item} key={uuidv4()}>{item}</option>);  
                           
          }))} 
        </form>
</Container>
)
}
```

The issue is the storage option. As I said, it will log the value to the console but doesn't populate the dropdown. Here is the data I am using, which I cannot change for now.

```
const Products = {
  "handset" : {
    "hardwear": 
       {
    "Apple": {
        
        "iPhone 13": {
            "color": ["Blue","Pink","Midnight","Red","Starlight"],
            "storage": ["128GB", "256GB", "512GB"],
        }, 
        "iPhone 13 Pro": {
            "color": ["Sierra Blue","Gold","Graphite","Silver"],
            "storage": ["128GB", "256GB", "512GB", "1 Terabyte"],
        },
}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
You should use map instead of forEach.

In your options for storage select you put your item as a string. Remove the double quotes around item:

```
    <select name="storage" className="hardwear" value={storage} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value="">Storage</option>
        { model && (Products["handset"]["hardwear"][state.make][state.model]["storage"].map(item => {
              console.log(item)
              return (<option value={item} key={uuidv4()}>{item}</option>);  
                    
            })
        )
        }
  </select>
```

It might be a copy paste error but you are also missing a closing select in your code.

Comment: good catch but that isn't the issue. Same thing when {item} is not in quotes.

Comment: so you have no options at all? Not even the first <option>Storage</option>? And no errors in the console or when building the project?

Comment: Poku the dropdown just has "Storage" in it, which is the default value.

Comment: @MarkScholes see my edit in the answer :)

Comment: thank you that worked. So you changed it from a forEach to a map. Was that your only change? Is there a reason forEach wouldn't work in this situation. This is my first real project :)

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you :) About the map vs forEach I think an article can explain that better than me :) https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240242/discussion-between-mark-scholes-and-poku).